# How to search the boost docu?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to search the boost documentation for the function `boost::date_time::subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000000l>::subsecond_duration(double)` now googling `boost date_time subsecond duration` did not return anything. I was looking for a search field in the [official docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/) and in [my version](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/date_time.html).

Is the boost docu written in a way it does not get indexed by google? Or how come my search query doesn't return anything? Second is there a search to find the function in the boost docu itself?

I could not find one maybe I just missed it. My guess is that it is in some old version but I don't know which one, I'm trying to build an older package that complains about the function missing, but I can't find it.

Comment: I've tried googles site search, meaning you search for
"site:https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/ boost::date_time::subsecond_duration"
and this returned for example: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost/date_time/subsecond_duration.html

does that help?

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the site search feature, thanks this is what I needed If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it's easiest for these documentations to use google's site search function which means your query becomes:

"site:boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0 boost::date_time::subsecond_duration"

This only yields a couple results of which one of them is:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost/date_time/subsecond_duration.html